# update multiple rows after insert in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, rows

After insert I want to update field with `($id.'mytext')` where in db that field is empty for all rows.

```
table name: peca
columns: 
id -autoincrement
A -varchar user insert
CB -varchar auto insert with update
```

```
MODEL WILL RETURN ALL ROWS WHERE CB=empty 

function model1() {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('peca');
        $this->db->where('CB', '');
        //$this->db->where('id', $fileid); 
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query) {
            return $query->result();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
MODEL WILL update in db where CB=empty 
function model2($dados = NULL) {
        if ($dados !== NULL) {
        //  extract($dados);
         $this->db->where('CB', '');
            $this->db->update('peca', $dados);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

```
CONTROLLER

 $this->load->model('model_peca');
            $resultadocadastropeca = $this->model_peca->model1($id);
            $data = 'id' => $id;
            $appointment = array('codigoean' => $data.'.PECA.');    
            $appointment = $this->model_peca->model2($appointment);
```

START TABLE
Previous values inserted from import so CB can only be generated after id exists

```
id|CB      |
22|        |
31|        |
```

RESULTS
I'm changing CB to .PECA. in all rows where CB=empty but $id for each row is not passing

```
id|CB    |
22|.PECA.|
31|.PECA.|
```

EXPECTED

```
id|CB      |
22|22.PECA.|
31|31.PECA.|
```

Comment: assuming your `id` is unique (and it is because it is a ai primary key), then these two statements don't make sense together `$this->db->where('id', $lastId);` and `1 row but not sure how to for *all the rows* where column is empty`. how can you modify more than 1 row when you specify only 1 row to modify? if you truly want to modify more than 1 row, you cannot have a `where` where it will only access 1 row.

Comment: My bad i had it with lastid when i was doing line by line. When i use form and i only insert one line in db so i fetch lastid and it works. Now i have to fetch all rows id where CB is blank (so i don't redo all the db). Yes id=PK. Not sure how to fetch all rows where CB field=empty.

Comment: Maybe something in this area:     $appointment = array('CB' => $id'.PECA.');  
$data = array(
               
               'CB' => $appointment,
            );
$this->db->where('CB', '');
$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('peca', $data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't fully understand what you want to do, but if you want to fetch something where a column is empty or null:

`$this->db->where("WHERE  yourColumn IS NULL OR yourColumn = ''");`

---

As per your revised question, this should work:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->where('CB', '');
$q = $this->db->get('peca');
if ($q->num_rows() == 0) {
   die('nothing to do here');
}
$res = $q->result();
foreach ($res as $item) {
     $data[] = array('id' => $item->id, 'CB' => $item->id . '.PECA.');
}
$this->db->update_batch('peca', $data, 'id');
```

Comment: So basically, where CB is empty you want to add the `id`.`.PECA.`?

Comment: Thanks it works i know it looks simple but i would never got there

Comment: the thing that most helped my knowledge of coding is actually understanding arrays and loops. i suggest taking time to master those two and you will see a great increase in your abilities!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Just started recently with codeigniter and programing.